# Prove that the matrix multiplication of a set of linearly independent vectors produces a set of linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

If *B* is a *mxn* matrix and *V* the solution space of the homogeneous linear system **Bx=0**, and there exists a set of linearly independent vectors *$u_1$, $u_2$,...,$u_k$* in $R^n$,

Prove that if *V* intersects span{*$u_1$, $u_2$, ..., $u_k$*} = {**0**}, then *$Bu_1$, $Bu_2$,..., $Bu_k$* are linearly independent.

And if *V* intersects span{*$u_1$, $u_2$, ..., $u_k$*} is not equals to {**0**}, are *$Bu_1$, $Bu_2$, ..., $Bu_k$* linearly independent?

Comment: Actually it is also duplicate to another question I saw here over the last week, but I cannot seem to find it right now. Maybe you should consult your classmates directly rather than all go posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\sum_i \alpha_i B u_i = B (\sum_i \alpha_i u_i) = 0$, then
$\sum_i \alpha_i u_i \in \ker B \cap \operatorname{sp} \{ u_1,...,u_k\} = \{ 0 \}$, and so $\sum_i \alpha_i u_i = 0$ and hence $\alpha_i = 0$. Hence the $B u_i$ are li.